# Normal and Tangent Vectors to a Free Surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, euclidean-geometry

Given a fluid dynamics problem in which the fluid occupies a region from $0\leq z\leq h(x,t)$, how would one find the normal and tangent vectors to that surface?

A paper I am reading simply defines them as:
$$ \mathbf{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(h_x)^2}}(-h_x,1) $$
$$ \mathbf{t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(h_x)^2}}(1,h_x) $$
If $h(x,t)$ is flat and steady, then these definitions definitely make sense as in that case $\mathbf{n}=(0,1)$ and $\mathbf{t}=(1,0)$ as given by the formulas above when $h_x=0$. So I'm not questioning the validity just wondering how to quickly come up with that on my own for other scenarios?

Also, I can see that the prefactor is simply the length of the vector to ensure $\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{t}$ are unit vectors. It's the specific form that I don't immediately see.

EDIT: I am working in $2D$ but the two spatial dimensions are $x,z$. The meaning of $t$ in the function $h(x,t)$ is time, however, the meaning of $\mathbf{t}$ is that it is the tangent vector at $z=h(x,t)$.

Comment: Are you working in 2D or in 3D? What is the meaning of $t$? Time? Can you update your question with those elements? Thanks.

Comment: I am working in $2D$ but the two spatial dimensions are $x,z$. The meaning of $t$ in the function $h(x,t)$ is time, however, the meaning of $\mathbf{t}$ is that it is the tangent vector at $z=h(x,t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 2-d case, you can think of the tangent vector of a curve $(x(s),z(s))$ as (*not* a unit vector)

$${\bf t}(s)=(x'(s),z'(s))$$

and then the normal vector can be found by rotating this 90 degrees depending on the way your surface is orientated, and which direction arc-length $s$ is being taken. If you consider a part of your free surface to be pointing from top-left to bottom-right, then $x'(s)<0$ but $z'(s) > 0$, assuming that increasing $s$ means travelling on the curve to the left (locally anti-clockwise), then to make the normal vector to that surface point outwards and upwards, you can rotate your tangent vector 90 degrees clockwise:

$$ {\bf n}(s)=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos90^{\circ} & \sin90^{\circ}\\
-\sin90^{\circ} & \cos90^{\circ}
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x'(s)\\
z'(s)
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x'(s)\\
z'(s)
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}z'(s)\\
-x'(s)
\end{matrix}\right)$$

That way, since $x'(s)<0$, the $y$-component of your normal vector will be positive (pointing upwards), and since $z'(s)>0$, the $x$-component of your normal vector will be positive too (pointing to the right). It may just be easier to draw a diagram convincing yourself that this is the case.

For the 3-dimensional case, think of it as a special case of the following. A two-parameter surface ${\bf r} = {\bf r}(u,v)$ has (unit) normal vector given by

$$ \hat{{\bf n}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial u}\times\dfrac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial v}}{\left|\dfrac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial u}\times\dfrac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial v}\right|}.$$

In your particular case, but ignoring time-dependence, the parametrisation of the free surface $z = h(x,y)$ is given by ${\bf r}(x,y)=x{\bf i}+y{\bf j}+h(x,y){\bf k}.$

Then we have

$$ \dfrac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial x} = {\bf i}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}{\bf k} $$
and
$$ \dfrac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial y} = {\bf j}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}{\bf k}. $$

I leave the details of the cross-product to you.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and thank you for relating the two. Very easy to work out from what you have above.